# apiで取得した情報にオリジナルな情報を追加することはできますか？

Tags: api

apiで取得した情報にオリジナルな情報を追加することはできますか？

例えば、
hotpepperグルメのapiを取得してその情報に口コミ等を追加する。

apiの情報をデータベースに保存（キャッシュ）して、そこに新しく情報を追加すればいいのかな？と思ったんですけど、そうするとapiの情報が更新されなくなってしまうので。（規約違反でもある）

どういう方法がありますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hotpepperのAPI仕様で回答させていただきます。
下記がhotpepperAPIのリクエストサンプルで、指定した地点データ周囲1000mの店舗データを取得しています。
(引用:http://api.hotpepper.jp/regulation.html)

```
http://api.hotpepper.jp/GourmetSearch/V110/?key=guest&Latitude=35.660818&Longitude=139.775426&Range=3
```

上記APIのレスポンスは下記となります。

```
...
<ShopIdFront>J999999999</ShopIdFront>
<ShopName>xxxxxx</ShopName>
<ShopNameKana>xxxxxx</ShopNameKana>
<ShopAddress>東京都中央xxxxxx</ShopAddress>
<StationName>xxxxx</StationName>
<KtaiCoupon>1</KtaiCoupon>
<LargeServiceAreaCD>xxxxx</LargeServiceAreaCD>
<LargeServiceAreaName>関東</LargeServiceAreaName>
...
```

このレスポンスの中で、店舗に割り当てられている**一意なキーがShopIdFront**となります。
口コミ等の情報を独自DBで管理する際に、上記キーも口コミ情報等と併せて管理します。

データの保存はNGということなので、独自管理している口コミデータ等へのアクセスの際に下記APIのように指定店舗のデータを取得して組み合わせればいいかと思います。

```
http://api.hotpepper.jp/GourmetSearch/V110/?key=guest&ShopIdFront=J999999999
```

口コミDB(例)

```
|id|口コミ内容|ShopIdFront|
|xx|xxxxxxxxx|J999999999 |
...
```

Answer (score -4):

すみません。
apiの登録がありませんか。例えば：私のサイトからhotpepperAPIに新情報を申し込みができませんか。